# How to change button state upon press tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, button, widget

I am programming a calculator that does many things and I wanted to ask how to change a buttons state upon its press. I am working with the following code:

```
import math, sqlite3
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
x_are = Label(root)
x_are.grid(row=0, column=0)
x_are_ = Label(root)
x_are_.grid(row=0, column=0)
boo = True
bool_ = True


formula_entry = ''
def geometric_calc_press():
    global bool_
    def formula():
        global bool_, state, formula_entry
        if bool_:
            formula_entry = Entry(geometric_calc, width=66)
            formula_entry.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=1000)
            bool_ = False
        def show_searched_formula():
            global formula_entry
            x = formula_entry.get()
            print(x)
        def close():
            global bool_, state, formula_entry, close, search_
            bool_ = True
            formula_entry.destroy()
            close_.destroy()
            search.destroy()
        if not bool_:
            close_ = Button(geometric_calc, text='Close', command=close, bg='black', fg='lime', highlightcolor="lime", highlightbackground="lime",
                           highlightthickness=2, relief=SOLID, default='active', padx=80, pady=20)
            close_.grid(row=3, column=0)

            search = Button(geometric_calc, text='Search', command=show_searched_formula, bg='black', fg='lime', highlightcolor="lime", highlightbackground="lime",
                           highlightthickness=2, relief=SOLID, default='active', padx=77, pady=20)
            search.grid(row=2, column=0)




    global root
    root.destroy()
    geometric_calc = Tk()
    bindings = {
        '<FocusIn>': {'default': 'active'},
        '<FocusOut>': {'default': 'active'}
    }
    for k, v in bindings.items():
        geometric_calc.bind_class('Button', k, lambda e, kwarg=v: e.widget.config(**kwarg))

    geometric_calc.geometry('400x415')
    geometric_calc.config(bg='black')
    formula_finder = Button(geometric_calc, text='Formulas', bg='black', fg='lime', highlightcolor="lime",
                            highlightbackground="lime", highlightthickness=2, relief=SOLID, default='active', padx=70,
                            command=formula)
    formula_finder.grid(row=0, column=0)

    formula_user = Button(geometric_calc, text='Calculate', bg='black', fg='lime', highlightcolor="lime",
                            highlightbackground="lime", highlightthickness=2, relief=SOLID, default='active', padx=70)
    formula_user.grid(row=0, column=2)
```

The only relevant part really is the geometric_calc_press function. i wanted to be able to fix a bug where the close button deosnt work if the formula button is pressed multiple times (the close button then needs to be pressed the same amount of times.)so I wanted to disable the formula button when pressed until the close button is pressed. I don't really know how to do that though so i am asking here.

Comment: By the way I know the code is a bit messy but i didnt really know my way with classes last week and started it like this. Didnt want to change it yet...

Comment: That was a lot of code for a simple question. Please try to reduce your code to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry, I edited it and it’s reduced now.

Comment: problem can be because you create Close button many times - you should create it only once at start without showing it (without `grid()`) and show it only (with `grid()`) when you press `formula` - and later you should hide it with `grid_forget()` without using `destroy()`

Comment: other method is to use some variable (`pressed_formula = True`) to control if you pressed `formula` and next time skip code which create `close button`. And when you destroy `close button` then reset this variable (`pressed_formula = False`)

Comment: last method: every Button has `state` to make it deactive or set normal. `formula_finder.config(state="deactivated")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can deactivate button with

```
button.config(state="disabled")
```

and activate it back with

```
button.config(state="normal")
```

or

```
button.config(state="active")
```

---

**BTW:** the same way you can also deactivate other widgets - ie. `Label`, `Entry`, etc. Other widgets may have different states - ie. `Entry` has state `"read-only"` (but it doesn't have `"active"`)

---

Minimal working example

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred

# --- functions ---

def on_press_1():
    b1.config(state="disabled")
    l1.config(state="disabled")
    e1.config(state="disabled")  # or `readonly`

def on_press_2():
    b1.config(state="normal")  # or `active`
    l1.config(state="normal")  # or `active`
    e1.config(state="normal")

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

l1 = tk.Label(root, text="Label Text")
l1.pack()

e1 = tk.Entry(root)
e1.insert(0, "Entry Text")
e1.pack()

b1 = tk.Button(root, text="Deactivate", command=on_press_1)
b1.pack()

b2 = tk.Button(root, text="Activate", command=on_press_2)
b2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```