# How do I make this button be disabled and say "Booked" when clicked in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

So, im designing a restaurant management system using tkinter and im trying to make the table booking system right now ive got a button setup to book the table and i want it so when its clicked it becomes gray and says booked but idk how to do that
can anyone help
thanks

```
window = Tk()
window.title("Restaurant Manager V2")
window.geometry("600x300")
#setup tkinter label
label1 = Label(window, text="Click button to book table")
label1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)
#setup tkinter button
def button_click():


button1 = Button(window, text="Table 1", width=5, command=button_click)
button1.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change button state upon press tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65206979/how-to-change-button-state-upon-press-tkinter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def button_click():
    button1.config(state="disabled", text="Booked")
```

Comment: Why don't you just configure the two options in one `.config()`?

Comment: @acw1668 To put it simply, I have a strong dislike for `tkinter` documentation. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

you can this with 2nd way

```
def button_click():
             
                 button1 = Button(window, text="Booked !", width=5, 
                           state="disabled")
                 button1.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
```

Comment: That's not a good solution, you are creating new object which might cause unexpected issues later on